# Getting exceptions on SignalR connection start method

Tags: asp.net, signalr

I am creating an application using `SignalR`. I have followed all configurations required to start working with `SignalR` like below.
 Startup Class

```
[assembly: OwinStartup("TestingConfiguration", typeof(UsingFoundation.Startup))]

namespace UsingFoundation
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            string sqlConnectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ProjectDBEntities"].ConnectionString;
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(sqlConnectionString))
            {
                GlobalHost.DependencyResolver.UseSqlServer(sqlConnectionString);
            }
            app.MapSignalR();
        }
    }
}
```

AppSettings

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="owin:appStartup" value="TestingConfiguration" />
  </appSettings>
```

Hub Class

```
namespace UsingFoundation
{
    [HubName("chathub")]
    public class ChatHubClass : Hub
    {
        public void Hello()
        {
            Clients.All.hello();
        }
    }
}
```

now when i am going to start my hub connection i am getting this below error from `Chrome console`.
[image: Error Window]

Scripts Link to Page

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.0.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/signalr/hubs" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Resolved'
I am using`SignalR SQL Server`integration with`EntityFramework`. Error is is`ConnectionString`.`EntityFramework` Connection String not working which include path to XML files.

> NOT WORKING

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="ProjectDBEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/ProjectModel.csdl|res://*/ProjectModel.ssdl|res://*/ProjectModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=(local);initial catalog=ProjectDB;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>

WORKING

"data source=(local);initial catalog=ProjectDB;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework";
```